# Using cuBLAS with complex numbers from Thrust

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, cublas

In my code I use arrays with complex numbers from thrust library and I would like to use cublasZgeam() in order to transpose the array.

Using complex numbers from cuComplex.h is not a preferable option since I do a lot of arithmetic on the array and cuComplex doesnt have defined operators such as * +=.

This is how I defined array which I want to transpose

```
thrust::complex<float> u[xmax][xmax];
```

I have found this https://github.com/jtravs/cuda_complex, but using it as such:

```
#include "cuComplex.hpp"
```

doesnt allow me to use mentioned operators when compiled with nvcc

```
error: no operator "+=" matches these operands
        operand types are: cuComplex += cuComplex
```

Is there some solution to this? Code from github is old and there may lay the issue or maybe I am using it wrong

EDIT: Here is code which works, only difference from talonmies code is adding simple kernel and pointer to same data but being thrust::complex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ void test(thrust::complex<double>* u) {

  u[0] += thrust::complex<double>(3.3,3.3);
}

int main()
{
  int xmax = 100;
  thrust::complex<double>  u[xmax][xmax];
  double arrSize = sizeof(thrust::complex<double>) * xmax * xmax;

  thrust::fill(&u[0][0], &u[0][0] + (xmax * xmax), thrust::complex<double>(1.0,1.0));
  u[49][51] += thrust::complex<double>(665.0,665.0);
  u[51][49] *= 2.0;

  cout << "Before:" << endl;
  cout << u[49][51] << endl;
  cout << u[51][49] << endl;
  cout << u[0][0] << endl;

  thrust::complex<double> alpha(1.0, 0.0);
  thrust::complex<double> beta(0.0, 0.0);
  cublasHandle_t handle;
  cublasCreate(&handle);

  cuDoubleComplex* d_u;
  cuDoubleComplex* d_v;
  cuDoubleComplex* _alpha = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(&alpha);
  cuDoubleComplex* _beta = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(&beta);
  cudaMalloc(&d_u, arrSize);
  cudaMalloc(&d_v, arrSize);
  cudaMemcpy(d_u, &u[0][0], arrSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  thrust::complex<double>* d_vTest = reinterpret_cast<thrust::complex<double>* >(d_v);
  cublasZgeam(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, xmax, xmax,
                  _alpha, d_u, xmax,
                  _beta,  d_u, xmax,
                  d_v, xmax);
  test<<<1,1>>>(d_vTest);
  cudaMemcpy(u, d_v, arrSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  cout << "After:" << endl;
  cout << u[0][0] << endl;
  cout << u[49][51] << endl;
  cout << u[51][49] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't you use the C++ standard library complex types and functions?

Comment: This is what I tried and it didnt seem to work out https://pastebin.com/hCjPvdBm

Comment: @talonmies I have read this doc : http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/#cublas-lt-t-gt-geam . And I must admit I there is a chance of me misunderstanding it, but I also checked some working examples

Comment: GEAM doesn't support in place transforms, as you are trying to do.

Comment: You are right, sorry made mistake when simplifying the code.  But still std::complex doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite your protestations to the contrary, the C++ standard library `complex` (or `thrust::complex`) most certainly does work with CUBLAS. The `cuComplex` and `cuDoubleComplex` are design to be binary compatible with standard host complex types so that data does not be translated when passed to CUBLAS functions which use complex data on the device.

A simple modification to the code you posted in comments works exactly as you might imagine:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int xmax = 100;
  complex<double>  u[xmax][xmax];
  size_t arrSize = sizeof(complex<double>) * xmax * xmax;

  fill(&u[0][0], &u[0][0] + (xmax * xmax), complex<double>(1.0,1.0));
  u[49][51] += complex<double>(665.0,665.0);
  u[51][49] *= 2.0;

  cout << "Before:" << endl;
  cout << u[49][51] << endl;
  cout << u[51][49] << endl;

  complex<double> alpha(1.0, 0.0);
  complex<double> beta(0.0, 0.0);
  cublasHandle_t handle;
  cublasCreate(&handle);

  cuDoubleComplex* d_u;
  cuDoubleComplex* d_v;
  cuDoubleComplex* _alpha = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(&alpha);
  cuDoubleComplex* _beta = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(&beta);
  cudaMalloc(&d_u, arrSize);
  cudaMalloc(&d_v, arrSize);
  cudaMemcpy(d_u, &u[0][0], arrSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cublasZgeam(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, xmax, xmax,
                  _alpha, d_u, xmax,
                  _beta,  d_u, xmax,
                  d_v, xmax);

  cudaMemcpy(u, d_v, arrSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  
  cout << "After:" << endl;
  cout << u[49][51] << endl;
  cout << u[51][49] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

built and run like so:

```
~/SO$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 -o complex_transpose complex_transpose.cu -lcublas
~/SO$ ./complex_transpose 
Before:
(666,666)
(2,2)
After:
(2,2)
(666,666)
```

The only modifications required are explicit casts of the `std::complex<double>` types to `cuDoubleComplex`. Do that and everything works as expected.

Use thrust, the code looks almost identical:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int xmax = 100;
  thrust::complex<double>  u[xmax][xmax];
  size_t arrSize = sizeof(thrust::complex<double>) * xmax * xmax;

  thrust::fill(&u[0][0], &u[0][0] + (xmax * xmax), thrust::complex<double>(1.0,1.0));
  u[49][51] += thrust::complex<double>(665.0,665.0);
  u[51][49] *= 2.0;

  cout << "Before:" << endl;
  cout << u[49][51] << endl;
  cout << u[51][49] << endl;

  thrust::complex<double> alpha(1.0, 0.0);
  thrust::complex<double> beta(0.0, 0.0);
  cublasHandle_t handle;
  cublasCreate(&handle);

  cuDoubleComplex* d_u;
  cuDoubleComplex* d_v;
  cuDoubleComplex* _alpha = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(&alpha);
  cuDoubleComplex* _beta = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(&beta);
  cudaMalloc(&d_u, arrSize);
  cudaMalloc(&d_v, arrSize);
  cudaMemcpy(d_u, &u[0][0], arrSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  cublasZgeam(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, xmax, xmax,
                  _alpha, d_u, xmax,
                  _beta,  d_u, xmax,
                  d_v, xmax);

  cudaMemcpy(u, d_v, arrSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  
  cout << "After:" << endl;
  cout << u[49][51] << endl;
  cout << u[51][49] << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Perhaps something closer to your use case, using thrust device containers with a kernel performing some initialisation prior to a CUBLAS call:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

__global__ void setup_kernel(thrust::complex<double>* u, int xmax)
{
  u[51 + 49*xmax] += thrust::complex<double>(665.0,665.0);
  u[49 + 51*xmax] *= 2.0;
}

int main()
{
  int xmax = 100;

  thrust::complex<double> alpha(1.0, 0.0);
  thrust::complex<double> beta(0.0, 0.0);
  cublasHandle_t handle;
  cublasCreate(&handle);

  thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double>> d_u(xmax * xmax, thrust::complex<double>(1.0,1.0));
  thrust::device_vector<thrust::complex<double>> d_v(xmax * xmax, thrust::complex<double>(0.,0.));
  setup_kernel<<<1,1>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_u.data()), xmax);

  cuDoubleComplex* _d_u = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_u.data()));
  cuDoubleComplex* _d_v = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_v.data()));
  cuDoubleComplex* _alpha = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(&alpha);
  cuDoubleComplex* _beta = reinterpret_cast<cuDoubleComplex*>(&beta);

  cublasZgeam(handle, CUBLAS_OP_T, CUBLAS_OP_N, xmax, xmax,
                  _alpha, _d_u, xmax,
                  _beta, _d_u, xmax,
                  _d_v, xmax);

  thrust::complex<double>  u[xmax][xmax];

  thrust::copy(d_u.begin(), d_u.end(), &u[0][0]); 
  std::cout << "Before:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << u[49][51] << std::endl;
  std::cout << u[51][49] << std::endl;

  thrust::copy(d_v.begin(), d_v.end(), &u[0][0]); 
  std::cout << "After:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << u[49][51] << std::endl;
  std::cout << u[51][49] << std::endl;

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didnt clarify it but I need to use these operators in kernel which is after transpose and is omitted for clarity. I hope that understanding your concept will help me achieve that.

Comment: @MaxK: If you want to do the operations on the device, use `thrust::complex`. It is functionally the same as `std::complex` but has `__device__` bindings. There is basically no difference in the code I posted in my answer, whichever type you use.

Comment: This answer is very elucidating. Small issue: `arrSize` should be of type `size_t` instead of `double`, right?

Comment: That was, indeed, a typo/cut&paste error. Thanks for noticing